# Cassandra compaction taking too much time to complete

Tags: performance, cassandra, cluster-computing

Initially we had **12 nodes** in Cassandra cluster and with 500GB of data load on each node major compaction use to complete in **20 hours**.

Now we have upgraded the cluster to **24 nodes** and with same data size that is 500 GB on each node major compaction is taking **5 days**.(hardware configuration of each node is exactly same and we are using cassandra-0.8.2 )

So what could be the possible reason for this slowdown? 
Is increased cluster size causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compaction is is a completely local operation, so cluster size would not affect it.  Request volume would, and so would data volume.